# Shouldn't comment upvote buttons on locked questions be visibly disabled?

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, locked-questions, comment-voting

On locked questions, the upvote / downvote buttons (for the question and for the answers) are disabled, as in this screenshot:
[image: upvote count with no upvote / downvote buttons]
However, upvote buttons on comments appear as if you could upvote comments, as in this image:
[image: comment upvote button]
It is only at the moment of upvoting a comment that you are told that it isn't possible.
[image: comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting]

So, my question is:

###### Could upvote buttons on comments of locked posts be either greyed out in some way* or, like up/down vote buttons, be outright hidden?

---

<sub>* They're already light grey, greying them out would be quite hard</sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that the vote buttons are removed only on posts locked for historical significance. On other locked posts, they're visible and clicking them shows a [similar message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acYvK.png). Here's an example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/348196

Comment: I think this is a bug introduced by the recent change to always show the vote and flag buttons, whereas they only used to be visible on hover in the past. I think there used to be a JS code that would disable the hover handler, which no longer works as of the change.

Comment: @41686d6564 On the post example (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/348196) you've given ,the only thing that is locked is answer creation ; questions and comments can be voted on as usual

Comment: @astroide No, they can't. Note that only the question is locked, not the answer.

Comment: @41686d6564 Oh, I didn't see that voting on the *question* was disabled. I assumed that if the question's votes were locked, the answer's votes were locked too